# Class Values passing in C#

Tags: c#

I have 2 classes, 1 is creating a string of random characters and the the other class is used to test if the function is working. When i run the Tester class however im getting a blank screen? Im very new to C#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public class FileNamer
    {
        public string GetFullName()
        {
            const string pool = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
            var builder = new StringBuilder();
            Random rd = new Random();

            for (var i = 0; i < 26; i++)
            {
                var c = pool[rd.Next(0, pool.Length)];
                builder.Append(c);
            }

            return builder.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

And my Tester class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Tester
    {
        public string mytest()
        {
            FileNamer fn = new FileNamer();
            Console.WriteLine(fn.GetFullName());
            return "a";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: where is your `main` method? the entry point for your application.

Comment: [MCVE] would help

Comment: I have another class called Program, that has the Main method inside

Comment: Your example isn't complete until you show the main method.

Comment: @CyberCube Could you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48051665/edit) your post to include that class?

Comment: @CyberCube so where is `mytest` called from?

Comment: Vote To Close (VTC) until you show where mytest is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have rewritten your code in my side. It perfectly works.
My Main() method inside Program class is as follows:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Tester aTester = new Tester();
        aTester.mytest();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

When I have run it twice. 1st time, it has shown: rfg67i87lmwfks337k8znpx7uk
. 2nd time, the output is: l5d68178ez5t52hx0bqq97us0o